# Stuck on affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $(X,\mathscr O_X)$ be a scheme which admits an open covering of subschemes $\{(U_i,\mathscr O_{X \mid U_i})\}$, i.e. $X= \cup_{i \in I} U_i$ with $U_i$ being affine scheme.
Consider $\varphi_i$ as the isomorphism between $U_i$ and some $\operatorname{Spec}A_i$.
I know that for any $p \in U_i \cap U_j$, $\mathscr O_{X,p} = \mathscr O_{X \mid U_i,p} = \mathscr O_{X \mid U_j,p}$ by showing that there is an one-to-one correspondence with germs.

But I try to break it down and figure it out algebraically. So $\mathscr O_{X \mid U_i,p} = \mathscr O_{\operatorname{Spec}A_i,\varphi_i(p) = A_{i_{\varphi_i(p)}}}$ and $\mathscr O_{X \mid U_j,p} = \mathscr O_{\operatorname{Spec}A_j,\varphi_j(p) = A_{j_{\varphi_j(p)}}}$. Then I try to show that $A_{i_{\varphi_i(p)}} = A_{j_{\varphi_j(p)}}$, and I am stuck...

How can I proceed? The "isomorphism" thing really bothers me...

Comment: You may find <https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20782/ring-theoretic-characterization-of-open-affines?> of interest.

Comment: "Consider φ as the isomorphism between X and some Spec A" : is X assumed affine?

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny oh you are right. I made a mistake... I am going to rephrase my post. Thank you.